# how to set scroll view in android

Tags: android

```
    RelativeLayout blur = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative5);
    TextView name_tv = new TextView (this);
    name_tv.setText("\n\n   First Name");
    blur.addView(name_tv);
    Typeface font=Typeface.SERIF;
    name_tv.setTypeface(font);

    final EditText nameedit = new EditText(this);
    nameedit.setHint("First name");
    blur.addView(nameedit);
    Typeface font33=Typeface.SERIF;
    nameedit.setTypeface(font33);
    nameedit.setMaxLines(1);
    nameedit.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
    nameedit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Similarly i add few text view and Edit text dynamically in this class.The problem is when i add scrollview in xml it show me error.....

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relative5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    

</RelativeLayout>


THIS IS MY RALATIVELAYOUT

Comment: And what is the error is shows?

Comment: it show me Forceclose

Comment: Post a stack trace from logcat

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

i apply like this but it didnt shown scrollview in emulator :(